# ORACLE SQL - updatestatement for max technical key per ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I need to write an update statement for a table of mine.
The table contains a technical key and a customer ID.

I need to update a field in this table by raising the field with +1, but only for the fields where the technical key is at the max value for that specific customer ID.

At first I tried to write this with how I usually do it on MSSQL:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.VERSION_CHECK = (a.VERSION + 1)
FROM customers a
WHERE a.technical_key = (SELECT MAX(b.technical_key)
                         FROM customers b 
                         WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
                         )
```

I've since been trying to work with a WHERE EXISTS clause in the syntax of the SQL used in Oracle, but I can't seem to figure out how to work the MAX technical key in there correctly, so that only those rows are updated in the table. Anyone got any input please?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . In Oracle, the query would return a syntax error because `FROM` is not allowed and `a` is probably not recognized in the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE customer c
SET VERSION_CHECK = VERSION + 1
WHERE c.technical_key = (SELECT MAX(c2.technical_key)
                         FROM customers c2
                         WHERE c2.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It did indeed work. I did try something like this, but I must've wrote it incorrectly when I did. Thanks again! (as well as to the other contributor(s) in the edit on my post)